# Play Store Arrow Animation in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Last week I started developing on android. I'm making an app for the gym where I train. I've made the main functions so far but i'm stuck trying to add the animation when the navigation drawer is opened or closed. Right now the navigation drawer is fully functional but the arrow doesn't animate as you can see from the picture:

[Image](http://s9.postimg.org/up324r4zz/Screenshot_2015_05_12_20_29_23.png)

This is the link to the project made with Android Studio:
[App](https://mega.co.nz/#!fZ5VDbzB!jt7Ac_-L5AMi2UV8YXDM-bhkk9PHDNV-GFuTyLhW4QI)

This is the Main Activity. java of the app:

```
 package com.dev.lollos.argus1910;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Gravity;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;




    public class MainMenu extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

 public void OpenSettings(View view) {
   // Do something in response to button
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}



@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new Home_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Atleti_Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Societa_fragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Manifestazioni_Fragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Risultati_Fragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Storia_Fragment();
            break;
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;
        case 6:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section6);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void OpenSettings(MenuItem item) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainMenu) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class handles that animation. You have the class imported, but the code you've posted doesn't show that you've implemented one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync the drawer:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(<context>, drawerLayout, 0, 0, 0);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
drawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: To sync the drawer i have to create the drawer layout xml? Because right now I haven't got it.

Comment: the drawer layout is a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`. There's a [demo](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) how to implement it in XML.

Comment: Ok, I created the Layout. Now what should I put instead of <context> and <actionbar>? I' sorry if I'm asking you those things, but I never developed for Android in the past, only Visual Studio.

Comment: context would be your `Activity` (use `this`), and actionbar would be `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Actually, if you use the default `ActionBar`, you should use `new ActionBarDrawerToggle (activity, drawerLayout, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: I did what you said but it says cannot resolve symbol with 'SetDrawerListener' and 'SyncState'.

Comment: make sure you use [this one.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)

Comment: At this point, your best bet would be to have the demo working, then port it to your code.